# Shell script to select particular letters in a word and print that word ignoring other letters in linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, centos7

I want a script to select letters between a word and print that word ignoring other letters in multiple files.

I have file with same name but the middle name is different so I want to select that word and list it.

I have

```
backup-aniketn-05-34-23-Fri-Sep-2019.tar.gz
backup-checkte-05-38-18-Fri-Sep-2019.tar.gz
backup-aniketi-06-03-11-Fri-Sep-2019.tar.gz
backup-aniketi01-10-45-31-Sat-Sep-2019.tar.gz
```

I want to select names between the 2 hyphens and list ignoring rest of the words

```
aniketn 
checkte 
aniketi 
aniketi01
```

I'm trying to get this output.
I tried using cut command but didn't helped searching for a script 
Please Help.

Thank You!

Comment: "I want to select names between the 2 hyphens and list ignoring rest of the words" - What is wrong with `cut --delimiter=- --fields=2`?

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use below two commands to fetch the second element from name :

```
cut -d- -f2
awk -F'-' '{print $2}'
```

In `cut` command `-d` is for selecting delimiter and `-f2` will print the second word.

In `awk` command `-F` is for selecting delimiter and `print $2` will print second word.

Comment: Its working only for name which has particular alphabets if we add another after that it gives blank output.

Comment: @AniketMahindrakar Can you give me an example? This should fetch the second word from start for all the cases.

Comment: If the name is "backup-aniketi-06-03-11-Fri-Sep-2019.tar.gz" and so it gives the output but if the name there is alphabet or number after the name like "backup-aniketi0-06-03-11-Fri-Sep-2019.tar.gz" or "backup-aniketi01-06-03-11-Fri-Sep-2019.tar.gz" it gives blank output. I think it selects the limit of the letters.

Comment: @AniketMahindrakar So in both the cases the output coming for me is aniketi0 and aniketi01 that is because both the commands use delimiter "-" and fetch the second element.

Comment: [root@localhost /]# cut -d- -f2 /list.txt > final.txt
[root@localhost /]# cat final.txt
total 32
rw
rw
rw
rw
rw
[root@localhost /]#

Comment: if i have a text file naming 16K     /home/demo etc, I just want 16K      demo in my file how can I do that

Comment: I have a domain name in the list of other domain that indicates `Tue-Dec/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx.com-12.03.2019_15-08-26.tar.gz` which is different from other name so what will be the solution to cut only the domain name `xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx.com` including other domain at once

Comment: Just help me to select text between backup- and -date and put it into a text file